# Transcendental Equation

Tags: equation-solving

After playing around with the Planck radiation law for the spectral energy density, (differentiation and setting equal to 0 to find the maximum wavelength $x$) I'm stuck on how to deal with what I'm left with.

I'm having difficulty trying to solve and plot the roots of this equation. I know it's a transcendental equation and will have to solved numerically though I'm at a loss how to do this on programs such as Wolfram *Mathematica* 7 or MATLAB.

Could not get [this](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/PlotTheRootsOfANestedTranscendentalEquation.html) to work:
$$x=\frac{a \exp(a/x)}{-5 (\exp(a/x)-1)}$$

where $a$ is a constant

Comment: Please include your equation as code that can be copy and pasted - also it would be nice if you said what you had tried so that people don't waste time trying the same things.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't believe this can be solved on *Mathematica* 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plot like that in the reference provided in the Question can be obtained as follows.  Solve the given equation (with `x` normalized to `a` for convenience and without loss of generality):

```
Reduce[x == Exp[1/x]/(5 - 5 Exp[1/x]), x]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && -1 + E^x^(-1) != 0 && 
 -5 + ProductLog[C[1], 5*E^5] != 0 && x == (-5 + ProductLog[C[1], 5*E^5])^(-1) *)
```

and pick out the solution,

```
x = %[[4, 2]] /. C[1] -> i
(* (-5 + ProductLog[i, 5*E^5])^(-1) *)
```

Plotting is straightforward.

```
ListPlot[Quiet @ Table[N[{Re[x], Im[x]}], {i, -20, 20}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In v10.1 `{Re[x], Im[x]}` can also be written `ReIm[x]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Something I did not know. Thanks! Strangely, `Table[N[ReIm[z]], {i, 1000000}];` is slightly slower than `Table[N[{Re[z], Im[z]}], {i, 1000000}];`  measured with `AbsoluteTiming` - 2.5 vs 2.2 sec on my PC.. I would have expected it to be as much as a factor of two faster